# Return value from async function in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

This is a very noob question, sorry about that, but I cannot find the answer anyplace, including the senior people in my workplace.

I have the following Angular code:

```
function getID(): string{
        var varitem = '';
        this.someApi.getSomeObject().subscribe((item: Item) => {
              varitem = item.id;
            });
        return varitem;
   }
```

This code, surprisingly, works.  When I call him, I received the right ID. But when I wrote it, the first thing I realize was that the `this.someApi.getSomeObject().subscribe` returned an Observable, so the call was async, so, according to my poor understanding of async code, the `return varitem` will run before the async code, and this function will return'' always.

As I mentioned, this code works, but because I have this feeling that I was doing this wrong, I tried to rewrite it this way.

```
function getID(): string{
        var varitem = '';
        this.someApi.getSomeObject().subscribe((item: Item) => {
              return item.id;
            });
   }
```

But in this case, as you can see, Typescript complains because when a function has a signature that says it should return a value, that value must be returned as the last statement of the function.

Well, the senior developers in my workplace rejected my PR because what I mentioned in the previous paragraphs, but when I explained to them that this works, and I asked them some suggestions to make it better, their scratch their head and give me no answer.

So, community, can you suggest a better approach, and if it possible, explain to me what do I misunderstand about async code in this example?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good thing you have vigorous reviewers. They found a serious bug.

Comment: Yes, but it works (so, cannot see how that is a bug), and they were not able to explain why

Comment: That cannot work unless you aren't really doing an asynchronous call like an HTTP request and `getSomeObject()` is some kind of synchronous observable under the hood. If that's the case, it still isn't something you can rely on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike a promise returning the response with the return keyword will not return it to the function, as it's returning a subscription instead of a value. What you want to do instead is return an Observable and then subscribe to it.

You can modify your code to something like this:
(Here in the example I used RxJs [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator to return the proper value upfront)

```js
function getIdFromDB(): void {
  const itemId$ = this.getID();
  
 // subscribing:
  itemId$.subscribe(item => console.log(item));
}

function getID(): Observable<string>{
        return this.someApi.getSomeObject()
        .pipe(map(item => item.id))
   }
```

Keep in mind that in order to actually get the value you'll need to subscribe to the itemId$ variable or use the `async` pipe in your html.

This is something that's often misunderstand about Observables, so I definitely recommend spending more time reading about Observables and trying to understand the difference between using them vs async await for example.

** Explanation About Observables **

You can think of an Observable as something that stores values, and you need to subscribe to get those values, and subscribing is an asynchronous operation.

Without subscribing to the Observable, it will not emit and you will not get its value. You can return an Observable, but you can't return the value from an Observable unless you return an Observable and subscribe to it.

Comment: thanks for your explanation, but it is something that still cannot understand. Your getID function returns an observable, but my code already subscribe to an Observable, but it must return the actual value (the id, that in my case is a simple string). At some moment, I will have access to the real value, right? Which moment will be that? I cannot returning Observables and subscribing to those Observables and returning more Observables ad infinitum, right?

Comment: You could do this.getID.subscribe(value => { }) then do everything you need inside that scope. Essentially, everything needs to happen inside the subscription's scope. Your code happens outside of the subscribe and it can cause async problems because the subscribe act is asynchronous, which is why it's not recommended. So to answer your question you have access to the actual value inside your subscription scope.